# which data structure for a list of object with fast lookup feature

Tags: c++

I have a data structure and have to perform lookup on it, I would like to optimize things...

```
struct Data
{
 std::string id_;
 double data_;
};
```

I use currently a `std::vector<Data>` and `std::find` algorithm  but I'm wondering if another data structure would be more convenient :

- hash table ?
- map ?
- boost multi index container ?
- other things ?

EDIT:

Each time I receive a message from network I have to lookup into this vector (with id as key), and update/retrieve some informations. (Data structure have more fields than in my example)

EDIT2:

- I don't care about order.
- I have to insert/erase element into this data structure frequently.

Comment: What is your goal? How do you want to use this?

Comment: What kind of lookup do you need to do?  My guess is that given a `std::string` you would like to look up the `double` data.

Comment: How many elements in the vector?

Comment: @Neil: around 100 to 300

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on your requirements, but two possibilities are to sort your vector and do a binary search, or to use a map. Both can be implemented within about 15 minutes, so I suggest you try both of them.

**Edit:** Given your requirement that you want to add and remove things often, and the size of your data, I'd use an `unordered_map` (i.e. a hash table) as the first try. You can always change to another container later.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you care about the order of the elements in your container or not. If you do care, you can do no better than now. If you don't, a hashed container should provide the fastest lookup.

But it also depends on other factors. For instance, if you create the container once and never change it, then maybe an ordered vector, with binary search, will be best.